# How to display date from V2 OData service in a preferred format?

Tags: sapui5

I have couple of weird problems with the `sap.m.DatePicker`. As I always do, I searched for topics via google, they helped me, but not entirely.

#### What I want to achieve

I would like to have a `sap.ui.table.Column` in a `sap.ui.table.Table` and this column should have a `template: new sap.m.DatePicker()` with date formatted as `dd.MM.yyyy`.

#### What I have done so far

I am using a `v2.ODataModel` to populate a `sap.ui.table.Table` from an OData service. Everything went well until I decided to have the dates in the corresponding column displayed in a preferred format. At first, I was using only these properties, related to formatting in the DatePicker's constructor:

```js
new DatePicker({
  displayFormat: "dd.MM.yyyy",
  valueFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
  value: "{" + fieldName + "}",
  //...,
})
```

In this way, all dates are displayed in the following format

> Sun Aug 06 2017 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)

I remember yesterday reading in a documentation, that when I have binding, `displayFormat` will be ignored, which to me is ... I don't understand why is that.

Anyway, I found a solution, which gives the advice to set value like this:

```js
value: {
  path: colName,
  type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({
    pattern: "dd.MM.yyyy",
    //source: { pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff" }
  })
}
```

At first, it seems to work well and the date is formatted and displayed correctly, but when I try to modify the date in a row... For example, I choose August 6th 2017. What is saved to the database via the OData service is 2017-06-08 00:00:00.000. This is not August 6th but June 8th. I select August 2nd - in the database, I see 2017-02-08 00:00:00.000 - February 8th. Seems like the month and day get switched. If I select, for example, August 30th, the change is not saved. As far as I understand what the problem is - there is no month with number 30, so it refuses to save it. Totally makes sense. :D

Then I tried to add/uncomment the line `source: {}`. Now for every row, the date column shows empty, as if every row in the database has `null` as value in that date column.

Next, I tried to remove `displayFormat: "dd.MM.yyyy", valueFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd"` from the definition of the DatePicker template - nothing changed. Interesting is - no matter if I remove those two lines or not, I can still change the date of a row (the change gets saved to the database), although month and day are still switched.

Then I came across another solution, which said, that I should add a formatter like this:

```js
value: {
  path: colName,
  formatter: function(val) {
    return sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({
      pattern: "dd-MM-yyyy"
    }).format(val);
  }
}
```

This way, it all seems to work as it should. Now you may ask did I give up using the format `dd.MM.yyyy`. Answer is "No!", it just doesn't work.

**So, this is the main question, that I want to ask:** What's wrong with this formatting? No matter what other symbol I use, comma, dash, it always works (`dd-MM-yyyy` or `dd,MM,yyyy`). The dates are displayed with the corresponding symbol. When I try to use `dd.MM.yyyy`, it errors like that:
[image]
and like that:
[image]

Thank you all for your help! Will appreciate it!

---

**Edit:** I have just come up with the idea to workaround this issue. Unfortunately, it doesn't work and produces the exact same error, described above with pictures. Here is the **nonworking solution:**

```js
return sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({
  pattern: "dd-MM-yyyy"
}).format(val).replace(/\-/g, '.');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56954223 should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try using "dateValue" + "displayFormat" properties like here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/wkHv9s?p=preview

```
<DatePicker
    dateValue="{testModel>/myDate}"
    displayFormat="dd.MM.yyyy" />
```

Comment: @user2177283 did it help you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tested it. At first, it seems to work. For all rows I can see the date in `dd.MM.yyyy`. When I select a new row, it displayes normally as well. But when I looked into the database, I saw sth interesting. I selected June 6th and it displays it. But what I saw in db is `2015-06-05 21:00:00.000`. Then I selected November 26th. In db I see `2015-11-25 22:00:00.000`. Our time zone is UTC + 2 and we use DST. I can clearly see, that it is related to that in some way.

Comment: Additionally, I have a datepicker outside of the grid as an external filter. When I filter by the selected date - by date greater than 10.10.2017, this is what I see in Fiddler: `GET localhost:port/ODataService.svc/Items/$count?$filter=(Itm_DateFrom%20ge%20datetime%272017-10-09T21%3a00%3a00%27%20)`. As far as I can see, it filters all with date greater than 09.10.2017 21:00

Answer (score 0):

> - `sap.m.DatePicker` with date formatted as `dd.MM.yyyy`
> - I am using a `v2.ODataModel`.

In that case, bind `value` with the following options:

```xml
<DatePicker value="{
  path: 'ReleaseDate',
  type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime',
  formatOptions: {
    pattern: 'dd.MM.yyyy'
  },
  constraints: {
    displayFormat: 'Date'
  }
}"/>
```

<sup>(Assuming `"ReleaseDate"` is of type `Edm.DateTime`)</sup>

[image: sapui5 date picker formatted]

Here is a demo you can run:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel",
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
], function(ODataModel, XMLView) {
  "use strict";

  const model = new ODataModel({
    serviceUrl: [
      "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/", // proxy
      "https://services.odata.org/V2/(S(SO45750998))/OData/OData.svc/",
    ].join(""),
    tokenHandling: false,
    defaultBindingMode: "TwoWay",
  });
  
  const viewDefinition = `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" height="100%">
    <DatePicker id="dp" xmlns="sap.m" width="8.25rem" placeholder="Date"
      binding="{
        path: '/Products(0)',
        parameters: {
          select: 'ID, ReleaseDate'
        }
      }"
      value="{
        path: 'ReleaseDate',
        type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime',
        formatOptions: {
          pattern: 'dd.MM.yyyy'
        },
        constraints: {
          displayFormat: 'Date',
          nullable: false
        }
      }"
    />
  </mvc:View>`;

  const createView = () => XMLView.create({
    definition: viewDefinition,
    models: model,
    afterInit: function() {
      const fn = e => e.getSource().getBindingContext().getModel().submitChanges();
      this.byId("dp").attachChange(fn);
    },
  }).then(view => sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().registerObject(view.placeAt("content"), true));

  Promise.all([
    sap.ui.getCore().loadLibrary("sap.m", true),
    sap.ui.getCore().loadLibrary("sap.ui.unified", true),
  ]).then(createView);
}));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

As you can see in the network panel, the selected date is sent properly to the OData service without any issues. Just make sure to use the type `sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime` for fields that are of type `Edm.DateTime`.

For more information, see:

- Documentation topic: [*Date and Time Related Controls: Data Binding*](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e1ddc69c01474faf830a522db8c9238a)
- Related question: *[How to Add Date / Time from OData Service Correctly to UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593990/how-to-add-date-time-from-odata-service-correctly-to-ui/47603778)*